# Half-width overlay over slide using slick

Tags: css, slick.js

I have a simple slider consisting of images and text-only slides. I'm trying to set a background colour overlay on the slides, but I'm having trouble positioning and setting an exact width of the overlay in percentage.

Here's a codepen of what I'm working with: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RrewXV

```
.slide-text-half {
  background:rgba(130,20,20,0.8);
  color:#fff;
  padding:0px;
  height:100%;
  width:inherit;
  z-index:2;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
}
```

Setting a 50% width on the slide-text-half class sends the background into a frenzy and I can't figure out why. Any suggestions?

Comment: This appears to be working for me?

Comment: No, it isn't, I want the slide-text-half to only overlay for 50% of the width of the slide, not the full width. Updated question title too

Comment: I uncommented the width: 50% and got this. Is this not what you want?

http://puu.sh/mWzz4/0ec2e20f6f.jpg

Comment: Oh I'm with ya, sorry.  I'll have a play with it.  @GMchris what browser as I don't get that as was my thought.

Comment: @GMchris - interesting that doesn't happen in firefox

Comment: You have floated elements. It crash all layout. Try to put another property like `display:inline-block`+ `white-space:nowrap`. With that properties your layout doesn't crash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elements with `position: absolute` are sized according to its first parent that have a `position` different than `static`.

So if you want to size the div proportionally of the slide, you have to add a `position: relative` on the slides, and make sure they have the height of the slider with:

```
.slick-track {
  height: 100%;
}
.slick-slide {
  position: relative;
}
```

Here is a pen: http://codepen.io/tzi/pen/eJPmbZ

Comment: slide 2 and 3 broken in firefox - showing as whitespace - the text is white so not showing, and no overlay appears

Comment: Here is what missing `.slick-track { height: 100%; }`. Otherwise the slide-track has no height, so the slides have no height, so the content that are positionned according to the slides will have no height ;)

Comment: what is the slick-track responsible for?

Comment: The slide-track is the element that contains all slides et that move to display one slide or antoher.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add

```
.slick-initialized .slick-slide {
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Wow, could you just explain a little why this works please. Actually, this seems to break the other text slides from showing.

Comment: @tzi answered that question for me :)